# Possessive generic quantifier {m,n}+ not implemented in Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, regex, oniguruma

Possessive quantifiers are greedy and refuse backtrack. A regex `/.{1,3}+b/` should mean: Match any character except line breaks, 1 to 3 times, as many as possible and don't backtrack. Tthen match the character `b`.

In this example:

```
'ab'.sub /.{1,3}+b/, 'c'    #=> "c"
```

no substitution should take place, contrary to fact.

The result in these two examples differs:

```
'aab'.sub /.{0,1}+b/, 'c'   #=> "c"
'aab'.sub /.?+b/, 'c'       #=> "ac"
```

Compare this with Scala, where they give the same answer:

```
scala> ".{0,1}+b".r.replaceAllIn("aab", "c")
res1: String = ac
scala> ".?+b".r.replaceAllIn("aab", "c")
res2: String = ac
```

Is this a Ruby bug, or is it possible to motivate this behavior? Perhaps, Oniguruma for some reason implemented possessive with all quantifiers `?`, `*`, `+` except the generic quantifier `{m,n}`? If that's the case, why?

Comment: I am not sure the reason why Oniguruma disable possessive property for range quantifier - probably you should ask the people involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is intended in Oniguruma. [Documentation](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) says `{n,m}+, {n,}+, {n}+ are possessive op. in ONIG_SYNTAX_JAVA only`. I guess this is because of backward compatibility reasons, or?

Answer (score 5):

### What really happens

It seems that `+` followed by range quantifier doesn't offer the *possessive* property to the range quantifier. Rather, it is treated as whatever in front repeated once or more. Using `.{1,3}+b` as an example, it will be equivalent to `(?:.{1,3})+b`.

### Work-around

You can work-around this with the more general construct non-backtracking group (or *atomic* grouping) `(?>pattern)`. Let us use the general case `pattern{n,m}+` as an example to construct the equivalent regex with non-backtracking group (equivalent to Java's behavior when matching with `pattern{n,m}+`):

```
(?>(?>pattern){n,m})
```

Why 2 levels of non-backtracking groups? 2 are necessary because:

- When a match is found for `pattern` (one instance of repetition), backtracking within `pattern` is disallowed. (Note that as long as an instance has not been found, backtracking within `pattern` is allowed). This is emulated with the inner non-backtrakcing group.
- When no more instances of `pattern` can be found, backtracking to remove any of the instances is disallowed. This is emulated with the outer non-backtracking group.

*I am not sure if there is any caveat here. Please ping me with comment if you found any case not emulated with this method.*

### Testing

#### Test 1

At first, I tested this regex:

```
(.{1,3}+)b
```

<sub>Initially, I tested without the capturing group, but the result was so surprising that I need the capturing group to confirm what is happening.</sub>

On this input:

```
2343333ab
```

The result is that **the whole string matches**, and the capturing group captured `2343333a` (without the `b` at the end). This shows that the upper limit has somehow been broken.

[**DEMO at rubular**](http://www.rubular.com/r/8aTRCXbNLH)

#### Test 2

This second test reveals how range quantifiers `{n}`'s behavior cannot be modified to be *possessive*, and it is likely that this also applies for other range quantifiers `{n,}` and `{n,m}`. Instead, the following `+` will only exhibit repetition of 1 or more time behavior.

<sub>(My initial conclusion is that `+` overwrites the upper limit, but it turns out to be wrong).</sub>

Testing regex:

```
(.{3}+)b
```

Input string:

```
23d4344333ab
234344333ab
23434433ab
```

The matches captured in capturing group 1 are all multiples of 3. From top to bottom, the regex skips 2, 1, 0 characters respectively for the input strings.

Input string with annotation (`[]` denotes the match for the whole regex, `()` denotes the text captured by capturing group 1):

```
23[(d4344333a)b]
2[(34344333a)b]
[(23434433a)b]
```

[**DEMO at rubular**](http://www.rubular.com/r/CmnSuayFRN)

#### Testing code for work around

This is the testing code in Java to show that both outer and inner non-backtracking groups are necessary. [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/FLJEXC)

```
class TestPossessive {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String inputText = "123456789012";
    System.out.println("Input string: " + inputText);
    System.out.println("Expected: " + inputText.replaceFirst("(?:\\d{3,4}(?![89])){2,}+", ">$0<"));
    System.out.println("Outer possessive group: " + inputText.replaceFirst("(?>(?:\\d{3,4}(?![89])){2,})", ">$0<"));
    System.out.println("Inner possessive group: " + inputText.replaceFirst("(?>\\d{3,4}(?![89])){2,}", ">$0<"));
    System.out.println("Both: " + inputText.replaceFirst("(?>(?>\\d{3,4}(?![89])){2,})", ">$0<"));

    System.out.println();

    inputText = "aab";
    System.out.println("Input string: " + inputText);
    System.out.println("Expected: " + inputText.replaceFirst(".{1,3}+b", ">$0<"));
    System.out.println("Outer possessive group: " + inputText.replaceFirst("(?>.{1,3})b", ">$0<"));
    System.out.println("Inner possessive group: " + inputText.replaceFirst("(?>.){1,3}b", ">$0<"));
    System.out.println("Both: " + inputText.replaceFirst("(?>(?>.){1,3})b", ">$0<"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I came to the conclusion that `{m,n}+` becomes two consecutive quantifiers. See the difference between http://rubular.com/r/sMG8aWrnYD and http://rubular.com/r/e9O10dNQxA

Comment: @StaffanNöteberg: Yes, I also realized that half way and changed my answer. (If you have been reading my answer in the first 2-3 minutes).